# Need some help upgrading a tiny piece of ereg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, ereg, ereg-replace

I have this line of code I use for SEO purposes. The only thing is that it has an ereg_replace function in it. Now I get "ereg_replace() is deprecated" error.

Apparently it's not as simple as switching it to preg_replace and my RegEx-fu is not too strong. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
  //make it lowercase, remove punctuation, remove multiple/leading/ending spaces
    $return = trim(ereg_replace(' +',' ',preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','',strtolower($input))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.

```
$return = trim(preg_replace('/[ ]+/i',' ',preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','',strtolower($input))));
```

Comment: This is the one that actually gives me the correct result. I wish it had more +1 to give. I actually up-voted the other answer first cause it was easier but once I ran tests this gave me the correct result. I can't seem to take away my vote from the other one though.

Comment: @Serhiy Because I'm a regex badass. I saw his answer and I was like, "puhleaseeeeee, not even close"

Comment: @Serhiy By the way, your domain "wellcommentedcode.com" is sexy name.

Comment: haha thanks, I really need to do something with it... it's been a long overdue work in progress... your blog "eggheadreport.com" isn't bad either... could expand it to full-blown publication with a name like that...

Answer (score 3):

You just need to add delimeters

```
$return = trim(preg_replace('/ +/',' ',preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]/','',strtolower($input))));
```

`ereg_replace(' +'` becomes `preg_replace('/ +/'`